# Packaging NodeJs app which uses Tcp Server, Http Server and html page

Tags: node.js, http, tcp

How can I package this kind of application? I am sending data from a Html page to the Devices connected using Tcp Port to node TcpServer. I am using HttpServer in between to pass the data from html page to the Tcp Server. Is there a better way to implement this functionality?

This might be a dumb question but are there any tools which bakes everything into an exe or .msi file? I looked at node-nexe and node-webkit which I found not useful in this scenario.

Comment: Why do you need to package it?

Comment: i need to give this application to different users so that they can run this application from their laptop or Windows tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. I dont say its a solution for the problem but, its serving my purpose at this moment. I have used a nodejs Cluster to load the TcpServer in the Master and Http in the Worker Thread, So that i have a single js file to worry about. I have written a batch file to load the js file using node and the html file with the address.